# Parameters on time stamps in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') time_in,
CASE 
  WHEN TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') between '6:00:00' AND '18:00:00' then 'day_shift'
  WHEN TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '24:00:00' then 'night_shift' 
  WHEN TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '0:00:00' AND '6:00:00' then 'night_shift'
  END AS shift
from blah
```

Trying to make it so you can see what shift it is based off a time stamp I am pulling from a table in sql developer. Any suggestions or help?

Comment: 'between' is inclusive; do you really want 18:00:00 in the first bucket so the second one started at 18:00:01, or should the first bucket really end at 17:59:59? And is the column actually a date or a timestamp?

Comment: is there a way to subtract say 6 hours from the '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00' night shift so that it would represent as a night shift from the previous day?

Comment: You probably want [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31269273/266304).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HH24` creates zero-padded hours.  You might try:

```
select TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') time_in,
       (CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') between '06:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
             THEN 'day_shift'
             WHEN TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '24:00:00'           
             THEN 'night_shift' 
             WHEN TO_CHAR(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00'          
             THEN 'night_shift'
        END) AS shift
from blah
```

Comment: is there a way to subtract say 6 hours from the '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00' night shift so that it would represent as a night shift from the previous day?

Comment: @james_weasel . . . You should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Since `between` is inclusive, your query currently attempts to match 18:00:00 in both the first two `when` clauses, and 06:00:00 in the first and third. It will stop on the first match anyway, but having the same value in two clauses makes it unclear what you expect or want to happen. You also won't ever get a value of '24:00:00', even with leap seconds.

So you can simplify that a bit to:

```
select to_char(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') time_in,
  case when to_char(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') between '06:00:00' and '18:00:00'
    then 'day_shift'
    else 'night_shift'
  end as shift
from blah;
```

It *appears* that your the ends of your ranges are probably one second beyond what you need. If the first range really only needs to end *earlier* than 18:00 then that should be:

```
select to_char(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') time_in,
  case when to_char(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') between '06:00:00' and '17:59:59'
    then 'day_shift'
    else 'night_shift'
  end as shift
from blah;
```

Although you only really to look at the hour in that case - you might still prefer to have the full time to make it obvious what you're looking at though. And if the `date` is a timestamp you could even do:

```
select to_char(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') time_in,
  case when extract(hour from date1) between 6 and 17
    then 'day_shift'
    else 'night_shift'
  end as shift
from blah;
```

And if it is a date not a timestamp you can still do that if you cast, but it may not be worth the effort:

```
select to_char(date1,'HH24:MI:SS') time_in,
  case when extract(hour from cast(date1 as timestamp)) between 6 and 17
    then 'day_shift'
    else 'night_shift'
  end as shift
from blah;
```

Comment: is there a way to subtract say 6 hours from the '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00' night shift so that it would represent as a night shift from the previous day?

Comment: Sure, but your query ignores the day at the moment, so not sure quite how you would want it to work? Basically just `date1 - 6/24`, which you can use as say `trunc(date1 - 6/24)` to group by. Depends what you need really. If you want it in a where clause then it's better to adjust the variable date.